# No Response for WaitForMultipleObjects() function in Windows 7

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7, permissions, acl

In VC++, I'm trying to call  `WaitForMultipleObjects()` function on windows 7 platform for group of objects to get signaled and with no timeout. I figured out that this function call is not responding...i.e. debugger is going to this function but not returning back. Whereas, the same function is working on **Windows XP platform** and **Windows 7 platform with non elevated user**.

note: I am running the application as elevated user on windows 7 i.e. run as administrator.

So, is it as permission related issue? If yes, please explain with an example how i can assign required permissions?

Comment: What kind of objects are you waiting on? Clearly they are not being signaled. Why do you suspect a permissions issue?

Comment: I suspect a permission issue because this function is working fine with windows 7 non elevated user with same object/parameters.

Comment: Considering that the permissions for an elevated token are a superset of the permissions for a non-elevated token for the same user, I think it's unlikely to be a permissions problem. What kind of objects are you waiting on?

Comment: When you say it's "working" on non-elevated Windows 7, do you mean it actually satisfies the wait? Or does it return a different error code?